# Product Differentiability in $ \Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R$ and $F: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R^m$ are differentiable. Show that the product $G(x)=f(x)F(x)$     -$G: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R^m$ - is also differentiable.

Furthermore, show that for $a$ and $h$  in $\Bbb R^n$ then $\mathbf{D}G(a)h=f(a)\mathbf{D}F(a)h+(\nabla f(a)h)F(a)$.

I'm trying to prove this straight from the definition of differentiability, but so far I haven't succeeded. What would you suggest?

Comment: Suggest you post what you've tried and where you're stuck.